# Authentication in a webview

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-webview

I have a webview that points to a net core web application that handles cookie authentication.

it seems that after closing the application the cookies are lost

the authentication cookie doesn't expire so I don't understand why it's gone
do webviews delete cookies when the application is closed?
what needs to be done to prevent this behavior?

maybe i solved it. it was enough to add two lines of code.

```
var cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance;
cookieManager.SetAcceptCookie(true);
```

can anyone confirm that i did the right thing?

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{           
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    var cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance;
    cookieManager.SetAcceptCookie(true);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Comment: can you share your sample code? did you use a database to save cookies?

Comment: do i have to take care of saving cookies? do not persist when the webview is closed?

Comment: when you save cookies in a database, they don't be eliminated after closing the app.

Comment: I have not found an example of saving cookies on sqlite. in theory the CookieManager class should do everything but I haven't found complete examples.

Comment: Save any data like that using SecureStorage from Xamarin.Essentials